# Powered USB hub powers Desktop PC instead: what the hell?

Tags: power, desktop-computer, usb-hub

*I've just experienced an issue that to some might sound almost paranormal.*

There is this crappy chinese USB 2.0 hub that I have since a lot of time: it's always worked so I never changed it.

It has a Mini USB jack and four USB Type A ports. It also has a jack for an additional power supply (I'm using one of those that used to come with PSPs, since no PSU was provided in the box).

This evening I came back home and pressed the power button on my PC (*Asus Z170 Deluxe motherboard*) to turn it on. Instead of turning on, the PC stood idle, zero reaction. I thought that someone might have accidentally unplugged it, but then, as I looked through the glass side panel, my Mobo LEDs and even the GPU (*ASUS Strix OC GTX 1080*) were lit, just like when the PC is connected and turned off.

*Bad case button*, I thought, *nothing an RMA couldn't fix*, so I opened the side panel (it has no screws but rather a handle with a sort of window that can be freely opened and closed) and I pressed the power button on the board itself. Nothing happened.

I was half scared to death (for my expensive rig). I thought that the problem could have been something like burnt PSU or bad mobo, either case leaving me with no PC for several weeks minimum, not to mention disassembly/rebuild and shipping delays.

Now this is where things got all more dramatic but also interesting.

I reached the back of the case and turned off my PSU from the Hardware switch; **The PC was still on!**

I unplugged the power cable, LEDs were still lit!

I started unplugging each and every cable in an attempt to understand if I had just stumbled upon the magical recipe for infinite energy, until I unplugged the last one, that of the USB hub.

*The LEDs shut off immediately*

I reconnected the cables except for the hub one and my PC booted correctly. As I stared at this scene both breathing a sigh of relief and being utterly confused, I grabbed that cable and it **shocked me!** It felt as if I had been electrocuted. So then I knew some electricity was flowing through that USB cable. Since I had no PCs to waste, I tried doing the same with an old Raspberry Pi and - to my great surprise - after I unplugged the MicroUSB cable, with the Hub powered on and plugged in, the Raspberry Pi was still running and remained stable and functional.

My question is: what happened? Why was a hub behaving that way? Why was my PC allowing to be powered like that and even refusing to boot? And most importantly, even if I'm never gonna use that hub as powered again, I wonder if this thing is dangerous/can cause permanent damage to my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've stumbled across two phenomenons.

#### Backfeeding

[Backfeeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backfeeding) is where the downstream devices ends up powering the upstream device... In this case the hub is providing 5v up the cable to the USB host (*tsk tsk*).

This can cause issues in a number of ways, but most importantly (as is likely you've discovered), it can prevent things from resetting correctly or powering down fully.

#### Poorly Isolated Power Supply

Many modern switched mode power supplies are isolated - this means that the input is electrically isolated from the output... and should be able to "*float*". Many devices operate with what's called a [Floating Ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_ground), but a scary number of cheap power supplies actually have poor isolation between the input and output.

Poor isolation means that current can flow between the output and ground (for example), as is likely the case for you. This is often quite a small amount of current, and it will usually be possible to match the two "*ground*" points simply by connecting them.

This can result in an electric shock, ground loops (where current flows continually between two "*ground*" points - virtual or otherwise), and in many cases can wreak havoc when the two systems are connected / disconnected.

You may notice when connecting the powered hub to a powered PC that things reset, or stop working - perhaps the USB port locks up, or maybe even the whole PC reboots!

In the past I have observed this between wall warts (supply to a true earth), monitors (shielding to PC chassis), and many others.

I have in the past measured 50Hz @ ~115v AC, with around 500mA between a cheap supply's 0v, and a true earth (e.g: PC chassis) - not nice.

---

My advice? Chuck the cheap power supply far, far away.

Answer (score 1):

You should NEVER EVER get a noticeable electrical shock from a USB cable. Even with USB 3.1 power-delivery voltage should NEVER be high enough to be felt.

That USB hub is faulty in a bad way and can potentially fry whatever is connected to it. Even when just used as an UNPOWERED hub it may cause issues.
Scrap it. That is the only safe thing to do.

And keep an eye on your PC. Even though it may look to be OK now it could develop weird glitches later on, because some of its circuitry was exposed to weird voltages. (Stress-test the machine/video-card a bit with heavy loads. That may bring a potential issue to the front quicker.)

If it remains working fine after 2-3 weeks, you're most likely fine. And extremely lucky !